# How to construct Regex pattern Swift

Tags: regex, swift, nsregularexpression

I am trying to construct `Regex` but it doesn't work. Can anyone help?

I have a string, which I want to remove the following characters:

> *_-+=#:><&[]\n

And instruct also to remove all text between `(/` and `)`

Code is belkow:

```
if let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "&[^*_-=;](\\)*;", options: .CaseInsensitive) {
let modString = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(testString, options: .WithTransparentBounds, range: NSMakeRange(0, testString.characters.count), withTemplate: "")
print(modString)
```

}

Comment: By testing your regex in https://regex101.com, it failed because of the "-" character. Are you sure about your regex construction?

Comment: @Larme No! That is why I came for help in Stack :).. There is something wrong in my regex. This is what I need to replace by whitespace *_-+=#:><&[]

Comment: Use Do-Try-Catch with an error variable instead of `try?` and a nice error message will appear explaining that the regex is invalid. Lesson of the day: do not ignore error messages. :)

Comment: Ok. It just that it wasn't clear since you mentioned that it didn't work on Swift 2.0. Indeed, with your question title, it seemed to be related to Swift.

Comment: @Larme Thanks. I've edited my Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
"\\(/[^)]*\\)|[*\r\n_+=#:><&\\[\\]-]"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yP3xI4/2)

The `\\(/[^)]*\\)` alternative deals with *all text between `(/` and `)`* and `[*_+=#:><&\\[\\]-]`  will match all the single characters you need to match.

Note that the hyphen in your regex must either be double-escaped, or placed at the start or end of the character class. Your regex did not work because it created an invalid range:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Forgot to include, my String has new lines \n which I also what to replace. Where would I add it?

Comment: I updated the answer. Added `\r` and `\n` - just on case.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! All works perfect, only one that is still there is `–`  How do I remove it as well?

Comment: Do you mean a hyphen? It is at the end. If you need to match an em and en dash, just add like `"\\(/[^)]*\\)|[*\r\n_+=#:><&\\[\\]–—-]"`